# absolute position stay with parent of parent instead of parent

Tags: html, css

I ran into some problem when trying to position an absolute positioned div. its working as its should i guess, however i want it to stay with parent of parent instead of parent becouse i have a dropdown list and it will follow the parent down on the side when i want it to stay in top like first `li` with div is displayed. ive created a jsfiddle to show the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/trptR/
can this be done using css only or is Javascript a must?

HTML

```
<div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
        <li>example
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub example1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub example2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub example3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub example4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Test
            <ul>
                <li>Sub Test 1
                    <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Projekt</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>Sub Test 2
                <div>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="">Projekt</a></li>
                        </ul>   
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#navmenu{
display:inline-block;
background:red;     
}
#navmenu ul{
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;  
}
#navmenu ul li{
float:left; 
position:relative;
display:block;
padding:0.5em;
}
#navmenu ul li ul{
position:absolute;  
display:none;
border:solid 1px #333;
background:#fff;
}
#navmenu ul li:hover ul{
display:inline-block;   
}
#navmenu ul li ul li{
float:none;
display:block;
position:relative;
}
#navmenu ul li ul li:hover{
background-color:#EBEBEB;
}
#navmenu ul li ul li div{
display:none;   
width:10em;
height:14.6em;
background:blue;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:6em;
border:solid 1px #000;

}
#navmenu ul li ul li:hover div{
display:block;  
}
```

Comment: todo this, you need to remove "position" from your parent, in this case from "li". However it does get complicated. How i've done in the pass is have first and 2nd level menu in the same ul li tree (just like how you've implemented) but the actual content of the menu is in the same level as the parent's parent, or in completely different node. and use javascript to reference each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you remove `position:relative` from both your `#navmenu ul li` style set and from you `#navmenu ul li ul li` style set? 
http://jsbin.com/ziqov/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

think about using

```
#navmenu > ul > li{
  float:left;   
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  padding:0.5em;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

because otherwise your selectors overwrite each other.

Comment: The `>` selector targets all indicated children of the indicated parent in a `parent > child` relationship. See http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css_selectors.asp or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

Answer (score 0):

### Positioning is key

I'm not sure I understand the explanation of your problem, but I do think I understand when you say you have

```
parentElementTop > parentElementBelow > element
```

that you want *element* to be aligned to *parentElementTop* rather than the *parentElementBelow*.

To align *element* absolutely to *parentElementTop* all you need to do in CSS is to not set `position` to `relative` or `absolute` on the intermediate *parentElementBelow* and any subsequent absolutely positioned element will be aligned according to last non-statically positioned ancestor. In your case that would be the *parentElementTop* which is what you want.

Comment: If you look at the second dropdown option in Jsfiddle you find that the div will follow the parent down the page depending on of N elements in the list. I would like to have it to stay in the top with parent 1 of div all the time instead of sliding down with next parent.

Comment: Exactly. Set positioning on UL an not on LI.